# PARQUET : Problema de memoria ao rodar código em python

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho 12 arquivos parquet, um para cada mês do ano em um diretório x.
preciso juntar esses 12 meses em apenas um arquivo para posteriormente eu possa tratá-los.
O problema que eu estou enfrentando é que ao juntar os arquivos está consumindo toda memoria do PC ( 16GB RAM ) e fechando o código.

Alguém teria alguma solução viável ? uma melhoria no código ou algum tipo de arquivo ainda mais compactado que o parquet. Segue a baixo o código.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# arquivos presente no diretorio 
diretorio = r'C:C:\Users\User\Desktop\sla'
arquivos = [
    'nov.parquet', 'dez.parquet', 'jan.parquet', 'ferv.parquet', 'março.parquet',
    'abr.parquet', 'maio.parquet', 'jun.parquet', 'out.parquet', 'set.parquet',
    'jul.parquet', 'agost.parquet' ]


#  armazena os DataFrames de cada arquivo
dfs = []


# Carrega e concatena os arquivos Parquet
for arquivo in arquivos:
    caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(diretorio, arquivo)
    if os.path.exists(caminho_arquivo):
        df = pd.read_parquet(caminho_arquivo)
        dfs.append(df)




# Concatena os DataFrames em um único DataFrame
dados_concatenados = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)


# salvar
caminho_saida = os.path.join(diretorio, 'uc_2023.parquet')
dados_concatenados.to_parquet(caminho_saida, index=False)
```

Comment: Como chegou a conclusão que problema é o consumo de RAM? Quais são as mensagens de erro emitidas? Você notou que em `diretorio = r'C:C:\Users\User\Desktop\sla'` você repete duas vezes a letra e os dois pontos da unidade.

Comment: Olá, Boa Tarde ! gerenciador de tarefas bate 12/13 GB, O código para e aparece " error memory " e fecha.

Comment: Tive problemas semelhante e utilizei dois métodos, pois para cada caso eu usava o arquivo completo (12 meses) de diferentes forrmas: 1) Analise mensal do Ano: criava um parquet/pickle anual contendo uma lista com 12 dataframes para analise individual (list of dfs), e de cada um executava a estatistica para o nao. 2) Analise anual, indivudual --> Criava um df com todos os meses (a criacao acabava com a memória). Aqui aprendi que podemos usar um um gerador (generator), executando a concatenecao passo a passo, liberando memória a cada passo....

Answer (score -1):

Tenta utilizar o modo de leitura iterativa ao invés de carregar todos os DataFrames de uma vez.
Use o método **pd.read_parquet** com o parâmetro **chunksize**, com isso, você consegue ler os dados em partes menores, processando cada parte e liberando a memória antes de ler a próxima.

```
dfs = []
chunk_size = 10000  #quantidade de linhas que será lida por vez

for arquivo in arquivos:
    caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(diretorio, arquivo)
    if os.path.exists(caminho_arquivo):
        for chunk in pd.read_parquet(caminho_arquivo, chunksize=chunk_size):
            dfs.append(chunk)
```

Comment: Neste caso você não irá liberar a memória se está inserindo tudo na lista `df`, está apenas lendo em partes. Existe uma forma de escrever o arquivo final em chunks também?